# How to format output in C++

Tags: c++

```
int var = 0;
cout << var;
// the output would be "0"
```

but if I wanna the output be "00", what should I do?

Comment: Use an [I/O manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Answer (score 2):

```
int var = 0;
std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << var << std::endl;
```

A more interesting one:

```
int var = 458;
std::cout << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << var << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in c++

```
int var=1;
printf("%.2d", var);
```